# For a surface does $ \textrm{non-rationality + K^2 >0} = \textrm{of general type}$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth quasi-projective surface over an algebraically closed field. If $X$ is non-rational and $K_X^2 >0$, does it follow that $X$ is of general type?